# Why do I get problems when combining two large PNG images into one?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, libpng

Often, difficulties raise whenever I am copying specific colors from one PNG picture to a second one and retaining the second one.

One picture has some red data, and a second picture is background, thus creating a third picture that shows red as well as background, so stirring in both pictures

The problem is, it doesn't finish all the time. Whenever it does the pictures are small and obviously show color data of the same value.
So, why does it run well only for small pictures? Should I take something in mind whenever employing the library?

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {

    chnd_lstp cr, chrt;
    fcmath fm;
    string input;

    int h, w, i;

    PNGC pngc;
    picture p( &pngc);  

    PNGC _pngc; 
    picture _p( &_pngc);    

    png_color _clrp= { 0xff, 0xff, 0x00 },
    clrp= { 0xff, 0x00, 0x00 },
    clr= { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, bckgrnd= { 0x00, 0x00, 0x77 };
    /* */   
    cr= chrt= NULL;

    h= ::atoi( argv[3]);
    w= ::atoi( argv[2]);

    if(0==pngc.pngnew()) {

        _p.set_png_color( &_clrp, &clrp, &clr, &bckgrnd);   
        _p.copy( argv[1]);
        cr= (chnd_lstp)_pngc.get( &chrt);   
        p.set_png_color( &_clrp, &clrp, &clr, &bckgrnd);    
        p.set_nocopy( chrt);    
        p.copy( argv[4]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: My guess would be undefined behavior in your code however you probably need to add a minimal example that fully compiles and reproduces the problem.  [mcve]

Comment: I updated the post by code that actually compiles.

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you run into? Does your code run forever? Does it stop with an error message / error code? If so, which line in your code causes the error?

Comment: Sizes like 1600*1200 cause long delays. So, huge pictures have problems to move on. Moving from line 500 to 499 for example. Just stopping by pressing strg+c. Sizes like 700*700 aren't that time consuming. I.e., producing results like third picture shows. Yes, it seems to run for ever. For smaller pictures sizes it doesn't. I think there is no race condition causing errors. I thought there must be some general issue.

Comment: This line, "p.copy( argv[4]);", is time consuming and may never return. Instead, this line, "_p.copy( argv[1]);", is passed at a good pace.

Comment: I scrutinized further. I figured out that it actually finishes. One picture finished after two hours or more. I guess huge and uncompressed pictures just take much time at the moment. My code must be revised. I also take in mind that concurrency is ought to solve it. 7*1200 color lines as well as 3 or 4*1600 color pixels just cause long delays.